# Will the inherited environment variables be inherited as environment variables or as shell variables?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Say my bash shell have the following environment variable:

```
export a="Hello World"
```

If I executed a process from the bash shell, the `a` environment variable will be inherited by this child process.

My question is: will `a` be inherited by the child process as an environment variable or as a shell variable, that is, will `a` in the child process be exported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an environment variable.

This means that any child process that the child process starts will inherit the variable as well.

Testing:

```
$ export FOO=bar
$ sh
$ sh
$ sh
$ echo "$FOO"
bar
$ exit
$ exit
$ exit
```

Above, the shell creating the environment variable `FOO` started a new interactive shell. That started another one, and that one started another one. Within this great-grandchild shell, `$FOO` has the value `bar`.

Another test showing that if if a subshell changes the environment variable, the change is carried over into later subshells (but is not propagated to the parent shells):

```
$ export FOO=bar
$ ( ( echo "$FOO"; FOO=quux; ( ( ( echo "$FOO" ) ) ) ) )
bar
quux
$ echo "$FOO"
bar
```

(in this example, it doesn't matter that `FOO` is exported as `( ... )` subshells also inherit shell variables, but the the effect would have been the same had each `( ... )` been a totally separate process)

Note that environment variables are available to *any* process started from the shell, not just shell scripts.  It would not make sense for a C program or `awk` script to inherit them as shell variables as there is no concept of these kinds of variables in those languages (environment variables are strictly key-value pairs, whereas shell variables may be typed as integers, read-only, arrays, associative arrays, etc., depending on the capabilities of the shell).

Answer (score 1):

You can read your process environmental variables from /proc/PID/environ. So when you export variable, it is stated in this /proc "file".